# Reuse QWidget PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget, qtabwidget

I have a predefined widget with qtDesigner, and I want to use it in several tabs. If I add several times a new tab by adding the widget, it only does it once.
For example:

```
for i in range(3):
    self.tab_widget_name.addTab(self.widget_name, str(i))
```

Comment: You need to create a new instance of the widget for each tab.

Answer (score 0):

Such as @user3419537 mentioned, you have to create new widget for each tab, it's not enough to change label of the tab.

```
self.tabs = QTabWidget(self)

self.tab1 = QWidget()
self.tab2 = QWidget()
self.tab3 = QWidget()

self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "1")
self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2, "2")
self.tabs.addTab(self.tab3, "3")
```

Alternatively, you can do it in a for loop, but you might loose reference to the tab widget (if you don't mind):

```
for i in range(3):
    self.widget_name = QWidget()
    self.tab_widget_name.addTab(self.widget_name, str(i))
```

Comment: Yes thanks. But what you propose are 3 different widgets. I meant to have ONE widget (defined in QtDesigner), and reuse it at the same time, as a virtualWidget. With a widget open 3 different tabs.
Maybe the solution would be to create a new widget instance every time, referring to a predefined widget. I do not know if it can be done.

Even so thanks

Comment: But that is exactly happening - you have defined `QWidget` (it's your predefined widget) and create a new instance every time. You can of course define your own `MyPersonalWidget` and create it's instances instead of `QWidget` :)